# SSRS: Export Drillthrough Report to Excel From Main Report

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I have a matrix on my main SSRS report (Lets call it Main) which has the row groups:
Manager
Employee

Then my one Column Group has Count of Loans.

[image]

What I want to do is if a User clicks on "Click Me" underneath Excel Report, they could export an Excel file based on SSRS columns from a different SSRS report (let's call it Drill01). Basically just instead of going to the drillthrough report (Drill01), it should export that drillthrough report in an Excel format automatically.

Does anyone know how to do this or where I should search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.. have a drill down report that is formatted the way you want to see it in excel and render the report directly to excel via the drill down.. rather than just calling another report straight.. use the reportmanager link.. Use the Action - go to URL rather than go to report.. then you can specify the report link with the required parameters and the render style.. in this case Excel. 
something like this: assuming you have two parameter called test and test1 (for example)

```
="http://yourreportserver/pages/folder.aspx/all the way to your report folder /reportname"&"&test=" & Parameters!test.value "&test2=" & Parameters!test2.value & "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL"
```

Assuming you have the link correct.. it should just pop up asking you to save / open the sub report in Excel..

Comment: To figure out the exact path.. place the following into a browser and then just copy what you need

"http://your_report_servername_hosting_reporting_services/ReportServer/Pages/Folder.aspx/"

without the quotes ofcourse..